# What meaning of "when" is it in this sentence?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

> Setting: An air plane crashed and bunch of school students have been stranded in an island
>
> Student A : Isn't it strange? Here we are talking to each other... ***when***, since we're in different classes, we probably never would have spoken to each other if this hadn't happened.
>
> Student B : Oh, that's not true.

Why the author put "when" in student A's dialogue? Is "when, since" equal to "Because back then"?

Comment: The students are stranded **on** an island... not sure if that's a typo or a misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***When*** doesn't always mean anything to do with time. It can indicate circumstances of a hypothetical (which is almost to do with time), it can even describe current conditions. It can be used to illustrate current conditions, and is especially used to indicate surprising or incongruous conditions that make the sentence such a clause is attached to seem strange, unusual, etc.

Simple-ish example:

> Isn't it weird that we're talking like we've know each other for years, when I don't even know your name?

If the strangeness is called out elsewhere in the sentence or text, you could usually replace *when* with *and* without loss of meaning. It can be more natural to use *when* in that situation, especially when you want to emphasise the contrast between the two conditions.

If you don't call out the strangeness explicitly, it is used to draw attention to it more subtly:

> I'm here, interviewing for a highly paid position, when I don't even have my degree yet.

Comment: If I replaced it with something to indicate contrast, I'd use *even though* rather than *and*.

Comment: @JasonBassford: I don't mean to suggest replacing it with "and" is an optimal substitution, just that it's generally possible for this usage of "when".